# Как использовать рандомное значение повторно, в Python? ТГ Бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пишу ТГ бот-игру. Вывожу одно слово из списка рандомно, через random.choice(), но как запомнить, что бы оперировать данными в дальнейшем.

```
bag = ['Отмычка', 'Набор инструментов', 'Пила', 'Аптечка']

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def messagelist(message):
    if message.text == 'Новая Карточка':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Сумка: " + random.choice(bag))
```

Список более 200 наименований. Хочу сделать кнопку "показать карточку", что бы игрок не искал в чате, а инфа просто опять вывелась в сообщение.

Comment: Например в словаре или в базе данных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечая строго на ваш вопрос - надо ввести переменную zapomnit и в ней запомнить:

```
bag = ['Отмычка', 'Набор инструментов', 'Пила', 'Аптечка']

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def messagelist(message):
  if message.text == 'Новая Карточка':
    zapomnit = random.choice(bag) 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Сумка: " + zapomnit)
```

Comment: Глобально вы мыслите правельно, что надо где то сохранить :)

Comment: @СергейШ, зачем словарь или БД, если ясно сказано - "Вывожу одно слово из списка рандомно [...] но как запомнить". Для одного слова словарь или БД совершенно избыточны:-)

Comment: Хочу сделать кнопку "показать карточку", что бы игрок не искал в чате. А если нажмет другой пользователь, как вы думаете что произойдет?

Comment: @СергейШ, это уж, как автор напишет. Как запоминать, я ему показал. Учитывая, что все школьники пишут сейчас боты, не затрудняя себя чтением учебников и задавая разнообразнейшие странно сформулированные вопросы  "мировому разуму", то среди этого сообщества есть и люди, не знающие, что такое "переменная".  В приведённом куске кода ничего о конкретном игроке не говорится. И вообще ничего о том, что игроков/пользователей  более одного:-)

Comment: Ну во первых мне 30 лет, я не школьник, карточную игру хочу сделать с детства, вот решил попробовать сделать бота для своей компании.
По поводу zapomnit = random.choice(bag) , при нажатии на кнопку показать текущую сумку, всё равно каждый раз пишет новую сумку

Comment: Где в коде выше эта кнопка, и где её связь с переменной zapomnit?

Comment: Если ее вообще нет в коде, то приводите, а также описывайте логику взаимодействия блоков кода. Убедитесь, что  до вызова показа не будет вызвана "Новая карточка", и что zapomnit находится в области видимости куска кода с этой кнопкой. Приводить тут надо путем редактирования вопроса. Или создания нового.